# How to clear page Session Storage in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

In order to test functionality of pop-up I needed to clear browser session storage.

In this way the pop-up appears again.

How can I clear the page Session Storage in Nightwatch?

Answer (score 1):

To clear session stogarage I used Nightwatch `execute()` command.

In the page object function I added command
`.execute(function() {return window.sessionStorage.clear();})`

Answer (score 0):

```
 browser.execute(function() {
    return localStorage.clear();
 })
```